# What is bitbake error-Nothing RPROVIDES mongodb

Tags: yocto

Using a translator can make the sentence strange.

I use DART-6UL based on mx6.

Attempting to add mongodb to an image results in an error.

We confirmed that mongodb is in meta-oe
I added it to local.conf, but there's an error.

Let me know if I've done anything wrong

```
local.conf

> IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " mongodb"
```

> ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'mongodb' (but
>   /home/eco/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-variscite-fslc/recipes-fsl/images/fsl-image-qt5.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
>
> mongodb was skipped: incompatible with host arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi
>   (not in COMPATIBLE_HOST)
>
> NOTE: Runtime target 'mongodb' is unbuildable, removing...
>
> Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['mongodb']
>
> ERROR: Required build target 'fsl-image-qt5' has no buildable
>   providers. Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was:
>   ['fsl-image-qt5', 'mongodb']

Answer (score 0):

You can search a package recipe availability via http://layers.openembedded.orgayers.openembedded.org/

e.g. mongodb is provided by `meta-oe` layer so please ensure that you have checked out the layer repo

```
 git clone git://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded
```

parallel to other layer repos

secondly meta-oe is added to `bblayers.conf` file

```
 BBLAYERS = "\
 ...
 /path/to/your/workspace/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
 ...
 "
```

This will ensure that it can find mongodb recipe atleast

Next problem is that mongodb is blacklisted in master branch as of now because it can not be built see 
http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/24093/

This would need to be addressed. If you are using an older release then it might be fine